# vue.js lifecycle and page refresh not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I need a user to stay logged in even when a page is refreshed or a link is entered in the address bar of the browser.

I created some methods for in the store to save and load the user's data to local storage.

in *main.js* I load the data I need in the *created* hook like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App),
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadUser');
        const user = this.$store.getters.getUser;
        console.log(`VUE app created. Logged-in user: ${user.username}`);
    }
});
```

In *routes.js* I have a *beforeEnter* hook

```
path: '/account',
    component: Account,
    beforeEnter: (to,from,next) => {
        const user = Store.getters.getUser;
        console.log(`Should go to /account, user is ${user.username}`);
        if (!user.username) {
            next('/');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
```

I expect the vue app creation to run before the router method but it doesn't. When I refresh the */account* page the router *beforeEnter* hook is called first and the app creation second. So my user is unknown and instead of refreshing the /account page I am redirected to the root page with a login screen.

[image]

How can I get the expected/wanted behaviour when a user has logged in before and his credentials (JWT token) are in local storage, a page refresh will go to the requested page instead of being redirected and why is the router method called before the vue *created* hook?

My vue.js version is 2.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to dispatch your action in `created`. Dispatch it before you get to your router.

```
store.dispatch('loadUser')
// create or import router
// create Vue
```

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks. Now I see it makes sense. in main.js the router is created before the creation of the vue app.